# ajax form validation and redirection

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to validate a facebook token inputed into a form

for example, such as this https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=CAAAAUaZA8jlABAHEALn0TUsHikuYzZBZAaNXX6QacevLZCjSACDOHxZAEX3ZAHDXJZA009ltUwLucBj5APzZBnA8qoZC7qKZB3FYGaYq7oXreJ6n6O2YzhsRUnDs1G2m8FTXwxDgSHFmCWWDUpPIZBYVBslBEU1EXiGEpQZD&expires_in=87272

and then I want to output the token part in welcome.php

first i validate

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateURL()
            {
                $('#continue').css('display', 'none');
                $('#loading_bar').css('display', 'block');

                var x = document.forms["url_submit"]["url"].value;

                if (x == null || x == "")
                {
                    alert("Enter your certificate address first.");
                    $('#loading_bar').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#continue').css('display', 'block');
                }
                else if(!x.match(/facebook/g) || !x.match(/access_token/g))
                {
                    alert("wrong code!");
$('#loading_bar').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#continue').css('display', 'block');
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'welcome.php',
                      data: $("#url_submit").serialize(),
                      success: function(data)
                               {
                                    if(data == "success")
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $('#continue').css('display', 'block');
                                        $('#loading_bar').css('display', 'none');

                                    }
                               },
                      error: function(data)
                               {

                                    $('#continue').css('display', 'block');
                                    $('#loading_bar').css('display', 'none');
                               },
                      dataType: 'text'
                    });
                }

                return false;
            }


        </script>

                    <form method="post" onSubmit="return validateURL()" id="url_submit" name="url_submit">




                    <input type="text" autofocus="" autocomplete="off"  value="" name="url">
                    <br/><br/>
                    <center><input type="image" id="continue" src="submit.jpg" border="0" /></center><center><div id="loading_bar" style="display: none;"><br/><br/>Success!</div></center>
                    </form>

          </body>
</html>
```

once the code is deemed to be valid I want it processed on welcome.php

```
<html>
```

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] != "")
    {
        set_time_limit(6000);

        $x = strpos($_POST['url'], "access_token=");
        $y = strpos($_POST['url'], "&", ($x + 13));

        if($y == 0)
            exit("error");

        $access_token = substr($_POST['url'], ($x + 13), $y - ($x + 13));

            print $_GET['access_token'];

    }
?>


<?php echo $access_token; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

while the first the code does validate if the token is real or gibberish, the page does not redirect to welcome.php to process it. it just stays there.

Pretty much what I want is in page 1 to validate and on page 2 to process it.

Comment: you are submitting the form via ajax that is why its not redirecting.

Comment: i thoguht so. how do I validate it while still redirecting the user afterwards